# What is the right printf syntax when formatting a double?

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I'm stuck at the `printf` statement. Can anyone tell, what's the right syntax for `printf` when formatting a `double`?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.printf("%-15s %-5s" + " | " + "%5s %15s \n", "Celcius", "Fahrenheit", "Fahrenheit", "Celcius");
    for(double celcius = 40, fahrenheit = 120; celcius >= 31 && fahrenheit >= 30; celcius--, fahrenheit--){
    System.out.printf("%.1-15f%.1-5f|%.115f%.115f\n", celcius, celciusToFahrenheit(celcius), fahrenheit, fahrenheitToCelcius(fahrenheit));
    }
}

public static double celciusToFahrenheit(double celcius){
    double fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5) * (celcius + 32); 
    return fahrenheit;        
}

public static double fahrenheitToCelcius(double fahrenheit){
    double celcius = (5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32); 
    return celcius;
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you provide the expected output? These are the format rules for printf `%[flags][width][.precision]conversion-character`

Comment: *but I'm stuck at this point which I cant seem to figure out* What point is that? You need to tell us where you are stuck. What about this is stuck?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The problem was in the printf statement but it got fixed, thank you!

Comment: @Mureinik The problem was in the printf statement but it got fixed, thank you!

Comment: Also there is an issue in conversion `celciusToFahrenheit`, you should define a constant `static final double RATIO = 5.0/9;` and use it in conversions: `static double toF(double c) { return c/RATIO + 32;}  static double toC(double f) { return RATIO * (f - 32);}`

Comment: @AlexRudneko I see, thank you for your feedback I appreciate it! The problem got solved though, the problem was I had the precision before the width in the printf formatting.

Comment: Great @TareqEl-Sayyed I will provide it as an answer as well, so you can close your question, and help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the `System.out.printf()` format rules:

```
%[flags][width][.precision]conversion-character
```

You can find plenty of examples and explanation of `printf()` [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf) and [here](https://www.journaldev.com/28692/java-printf-method)